# Error when bodyPath() is used in creating a mock service

Tags: karate

My mock scenario is as below.

Scenario: pathMatches('/tokenisationservice/TokenisationWS_1_3') && bodyPath('/Envelope/Body/getToken/GetTokenRequest/enterpriseID') == '1'

url to be mocked- 'http://localhost:8080/tokenisationservice/TokenisationWS_1_3'

### Request XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope blah blah blah>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tok:getToken>
            <GetTokenRequest>
            <enterpriseID>1</enterpriseID>
            <merchantGroupID>1</merchantGroupID>
            <pan>1234567890123456</pan>
         </GetTokenRequest>
      </tok:getToken>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Running standalone karate-netty. This gives the below error and not giving the desired response back.

15:53:19.159 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] WARN  com.intuit.karate - scenario match evaluation failed: javascript evaluation failed: pathMatches('/tokenisationservice/TokenisationWS_1_3') && bodyPath('/Enve
lope/Body/getToken/GetTokenRequest/enterpriseID') == '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo in your mock / feature. I tried it and it works for me. Also note that `bodyPath()` was introduced in Karate 0.8.0 only

mock:

```
Scenario: pathMatches('/tokenisationservice/TokenisationWS_1_3') && bodyPath('/Envelope/Body/getToken/GetTokenRequest/enterpriseID') == '1'
  * print request
  * def response = { success: true }
```

test:

```
* url karate.properties['mock.url']
* path '/tokenisationservice/TokenisationWS_1_3'
* request
"""
<soapenv:Envelope>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tok:getToken>
            <GetTokenRequest>
            <enterpriseID>1</enterpriseID>
            <merchantGroupID>1</merchantGroupID>
            <pan>1234567890123456</pan>
         </GetTokenRequest>
      </tok:getToken>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""
* method post
* status 200
* print response
```

Comment: Hi, I copied the scenario line from your comment but still the same error. Interesting to note that if I delete the '&& bodyPath(....)' part in the Scenario line and run it with just the pathMatches, the mock works as expected with the test.

Comment: @Sindhu - ok time for me to point you to this process, all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Another observation - the same statement works without any issues in a maven project but fails when run standalone. Karate-netty-0.9.1 is used as the standalone jar. Same version is used in maven too. Do I need to attach a maven project for creating the issue in Git?

Comment: @Sindhu karate-netty !? in this case upload a zip file with your project structure - you can omit the jar but specify where you got it from

Comment: Will do. But concerned with your expression against karate-netty. Should I not be using it? Got it from here. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-netty/0.9.1.

Comment: @Sindhu that’s wrong. can you please read the docs and find the right link ?