# Karate input Match

Tags: java, testing, karate

In Karate I can create scenario for mock server using `pathMAtch`. Is there a possibility to create scenario based on input (**body**) to say something like this:

```
for input X expect response Y
for input A expect response B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `request` variable is always available to do JS operations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67589246/143475

And yes, you can use `bodyPath()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911983/143475

More ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63708918/143475